# Why no output when PLSQL Anonymous block completes?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I'm just getting into PL/SQL, and I tried to run the following code, and I am getting **anonymous block completed**, but I think I should be getting **Testing output**. Does any know what I am doing wrong?

```
DECLARE
   message varchar2(20) := 'Testing output';
BEGIN
   dbms_output.put_line(message);
END;
/
```

Comment: The answer depends on what client you're using. `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` is correct for SQL*Plus. Other tools have their own means for retrieving the results from `dbms_output`.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Viewing the DBMS_OUTPUT depends on the program.

**SQL*Plus and Oracle SQL Developer**

Run `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;` first.  This is all that's necessary in SQL*Plus or recent versions of Oracle SQL Developer.

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('Testing output');
end;
/
```

**PL/SQL Developer**

Output is automatically detected and displayed in the "Output" tab.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I set serveroutput to on and it worked. Is there a way that i can run it in sqldeveloper though?

Comment: That's cool. Are you running from CLI? And yes, when I was using Oracle during my module I used sql developer through out.

Comment: In SQL Developer select "View" -> "DBMS Output".

Comment: Dbms Output is opened, it is connected to correct connection, but nothing is displayed

Comment: I'm trying it online with Oracle SQL worksheet and it's giving `Unsupported Command` error. Any idea how I could work it out?

Answer (score 8):

Yes, in Oracle SQL Developer put the statement:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
```

just before your `DECLARE` keyword and this should work.

I couldn't find `View -> DBMS Output` and I'm using version 1.5.5.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. There is way to see output in SQL Developer.

Click ->View->Dbms Output and then click + symbol on Dbms output window. now you can run the procedure and can see output.

Answer (score 1):

`The following statement will give the possible solution try this out

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
```

**Then Run this code will get the following output**

```
declare
a integer :=10;
b integer :=20;
c integer;
f real;
begin
c := a+b;
dbms_output.put_line('value of c: ' || c);
f := 70.0/3.0;
dbms_output.put_line('value of f: ' || f);
```

end;
/

The code will give the following output

value of c: 30
value of f: 23.3333333333333333333333333333333333333

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is correct. You need to use before this block:

`SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`

Then, message get displayed on window.

Else we can check in SQL Developer `select "View" -> "DBMS Output"`.
and in `PLSQL developer` under the `OutPut` tab we can check message.

Comment: Where do you put the set block? In the declaration?

Comment: Before the `Declare` works for me

Answer (score -2):

```
**SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;**
DECLARE
   a INTEGER :=10;
   b INTEGER :=20;
   c float ;
   d real ;

BEGIN
   c :=a+b;
   dbms_output.put_line('the value of C is :'|| c);
   d := 70.0/3.3;
   dbms_output.put_line('the value of d is:'|| d);
END;
```

This will give you the output

```
the value of C is: 30
the value of d is: 21.21212121212121212121212121212121212121
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are getting "anonymous block completed" while executing the procedure by typing "EXECUTE ;" then run the below command & again execute the procedure.
command is

SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;

Comment: This simply repeats the existing answers. As such what additional value do you think it has?