# anonymous block completed in oracle SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

Whilst trying to create a query cursor as follows:

```
DECLARE CURSOR Query1
IS
SELECT * FROM RACE 
WHERE Race_Time='22-SEP-14 12.00.00.000000000'; 
BEGIN
OPEN Query1;
END;
```

I get the following error. anonymous block completed. Does anyone know how to fix this? I tried setting the 
 'SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;' 
before the declare but this did not seem to fix the error. Thanks in advance!

Comment: "anonymous block completed" means your PL/SQL code was successfully executed.

Comment: Oh right.. so how do i display the cursor results?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that dbms_output is turned off

you can see you out put if you put `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;` in the beginning of your script.

or you can view dbms_output  window (View then DBMS Output) then press the "+" at the top of the Dbms Output window and then select an open database

Answer (score 1):

"anonymous block completed" means your PL/SQL code was successfully executed. 
To Display: try using a output statement...

For example:

```
 BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line ('Hello, world!');
END;
```

Comment: I'm sorry but the example you have given there is just confusing as it has nothing to do with outputting my cursor but simply a line of text. Going by what you're saying to display what is stored in my cursor would it simply be:
    BEGIN
    dbmz_output.query1
    END;
Is this what you're implying? My oracle knowledge is very poor.

Comment: Look here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7887413/printing-the-value-of-a-variable-in-sql-developer

Comment: One more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14803195/plsql-anonymous-block-complete

Answer (score 1):

If you want to control the process in PL/SQL, you could do something like

```
DECLARE 
  l_race_rec race%rowtype;

  CURSOR Query1
  IS
    SELECT * 
      FROM RACE 
     WHERE Race_Time='22-SEP-14 12.00.00.000000000'; 
BEGIN
  OPEN Query1;
  LOOP
    FETCH query1 INTO l_race_rec;
    EXIT WHEN query1%notfound;

    dbms_output.put_line( l_race_rec.column1 || ' ' || l_race_rec.column2 || ... || l_race_rec.columnN );
  END LOOP;
  CLOSE Query1;    
END;
```

Unless your assignment requires the use of explicit cursors, though, implicit cursors are likely easier to use

```
BEGIN
  FOR x IN( SELECT * 
              FROM RACE 
             WHERE Race_Time='22-SEP-14 12.00.00.000000000')
  LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line( x.column1 || ' ' || x.column2 || ... || x.columnN );
  END LOOP;
END;
```

If you are using SQL*Plus, you can also do something like

```
VAR rc REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  OPEN :rc
   FOR SELECT *
         FROM race
        WHERE race_time = '22-SEP-14 12.00.00.000000000'; 
END;
PRINT rc
```

If `race_time` is really a `timestamp`, you should really be comparing a `timestamp` with another `timestamp` rather than comparing a `timestamp` to a string.  Use explicit conversion with an explicit format mask to avoid errors due to different sessions having different NLS settings

```
WHERE race_time = to_timestamp( '22-SEP-14 12.00.00.000000000', 
                                'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS.FF9' )
```

Of course, I'm not sure why you would use a `timestamp` in the first place here-- it seems unlikely that you really know the nanosecond at which a race started.

Comment: Is there anyway of putting text before the column fetched, for example if i want to put 'Race id:' Before the first collumn fetched is there a way i can do that? Otherwise it's just a number showing up

Comment: @user3357925 - At that point, you're just concatenating strings so you can put whatever you'd like there.  `'Something: ' || x.column1 || ' Something Else: ' || x.column2 || ...`